# How to override args in k8s statefulset using helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-statefulset, helm3

When running the command: `helm install singer --dry-run packages/helm-chart/charts/csm-im` on the following chart, the `args` is not set at all. Why?

values.yaml:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - args:
          - node
          - -r
          - ./.pnp.cjs
          - packages/csm-im/dist/src/index.js
```

templates/statefulset.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: {{ .Release.Name }}
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
    field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: '[{"addresses":[""],"port":443,"protocol":"HTTPS","serviceName":"default:csm-im","ingressName":"default:singer-csm-im","hostname":"singer-csm-im.octopol.io","path":"/","allNodes":false}]'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    cattle.io/creator: norman
    workload.user.cattle.io/workloadselector: statefulSet-default-csm-im
  name: csm-im
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      workload.user.cattle.io/workloadselector: statefulSet-default-csm-im
  serviceName: csm-im
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        field.cattle.io/ports: '[[{"containerPort":8080,"dnsName":"csm-im","hostPort":0,"kind":"ClusterIP","name":"tcpport01","protocol":"TCP","sourcePort":0}]]'
      labels:
        workload.user.cattle.io/workloadselector: statefulSet-default-csm-im
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: RESEARCH_ENABLE_CALL
              value: 'false'
          image: image1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 20
            periodSeconds: 2
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 2
          name: csm-im
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: tcpport01
              protocol: TCP
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /readiness
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 2
            successThreshold: 2
            timeoutSeconds: 2
          resources: {}
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            capabilities: {}
            privileged: false
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
            runAsNonRoot: false
          stdin: true
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          tty: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: octopol-dockerhub-credentials
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  updateStrategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      partition: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
```

Answer (score 0):

To add values to your template with `values.yaml` you need to have a space for the values in your template. Fo example to add `baz` from

```yaml
foo:
  bar: baz
```

in the template, you need to add

```yaml
{{ .Values.foo.bar }}
```

Since you have the containers manifest already in your template, you could add

```yaml
{{ .Values.spec.template.containers.args }}
```

Since this is a list, you have to iterate through ith with `{{ range }}`

```yaml
{{ range .Values.spec.template.containers.args }}
```

so, like

```yaml
...
spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: RESEARCH_ENABLE_CALL
              value: 'false'
          image: image1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
        - args: {{ range .Values.spec.template.containers.args | nindent 10 }}
...
```

`nindent 10` add indentation with leading newline.

Comment: hi, i was going to come back to it in the weekend and check it out. @p1ol answer looks great